# Remove Right click options from eclipse rcp plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have created a rcp plugin in eclipse. On right clicking of perspective title, I get following options : [image: Menu Options]

I want to either remove or disable "close option" from it. 
I have tried folowing options:

**Option1**

```
layout.getViewLayout("plugin_id").setCloseable(false);
```

**Result:** Didn't work.

**Option2**

```
 <plugin>
   <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
     <handler
       class="example.commands.UnsupportedCommandEliminator"
       commandId="org.eclipse.ui.window.closePerspective">
     </handler>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

**Result:** Didn't work.

**Option3**

```
private void disablePerspectiveToolbarMenu() {
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = 
      PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (workbenchWindow == null) {
      return;
    }
    PerspectiveBarManager perspectiveBarManager = 
    ((WorkbenchWindow)workbenchWindow).getPerspectiveBar();
    if (perspectiveBarManager == null) {
     return;
    }
    ToolBar toolBar = perspectiveBarManager.getControl();
    Listener[] listeners = toolBar.getListeners(SWT.MenuDetect);
    if (listeners != null){
    for (Listener listener : listeners){
     toolBar.removeListener(SWT.MenuDetect, listener);
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:** Gives compilation error on getPerspectiveBar() function.

Comment: This menu is created by `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher`. It doesn't appear to have any way to suppress the Close menu item.

Comment: @greg-449 is there any way to override "close" button functioning?

Comment: Well it appears to be an e4 AddOn so you might be able to build your RCP using a modified Legacy.e4xmi using different code for that addon.

Comment: @greg-449 I didn't get you, is it possible to override the close button functionality ?